# Investigating the Impact of Additive Gaussian Noise on EEG Signal Classification: Analyzing the Relationship between Augmented and Original Data

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, data-augmentation, gaussian, noise

**Definition**: I have conducted research on EEG signal classification, specifically focusing on distinguishing between two different classes using raw EEG signals. Data availability poses a significant challenge in the EEG domain, which necessitates the implementation of data augmentation techniques. In my case, I have applied additive Gaussian noise with zero mean and varying standard deviations (σ∈{0.1,0.01,0.001}) to the raw EEG signals for data augmentation. Additionally, I have considered the magnification factor (m∈{1,2,3}) for the additive noise. By augmenting my training data using different combinations of m and σ, I have observed an improvement in test set accuracy in most cases.

**Question**: Considering the training data as X_train, the augmented data as X_train_aug, and the test data as X_test, I would like to determine if there exists a mathematical relationship between (X_train, X_test) and (X_train_aug, X_test) that can explain the observed improvement. Are there any criteria available for measuring the relationship between these variables that can help elucidate the results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the improvement you observe may be simply attibuted to having *more training data*, allowing to better exploit the capacity of your model: meaning better accuracy, and wider generalization.

Another (or additional) option, is that the added noise regularizes your model making it more robust (and better on test-set.)

If you increase the noise too much, you should observe decreasing performance. Also, Gaussian noise have the nice property of being zero-centered (i.e. its mean is zero) so that it cancels-out on average.

Comment: you adequately addressed some factors that may impact my results. However, the challenge lies in examining potential mathematical/statistical/probabilistic relationships between (X_train, X_test) or (X_train_aug, X_test) that can elucidate the reasons behind the observed performance improvements in certain cases and the lack thereof in others. As previously mentioned and confirmed by you, in some instances, the selected configuration (comprising a combination of magnification factor and standard deviation of additive noise) does not yield a model capable of accurately classifying X_test.

Comment: Right. Maybe you can try to compute the correlation between X_train and X_train_aug (same for test), like *Pearson* (which is linear) of something more powerful based on *mutual information* (able to capture non-linear correlations.) In the latter case, I guess you can first bin you data to get a histogram, so a distribution and then compute MI